# Error in table list after compile the document - spacing between de lines

Tags: tables, spacing, errors, lists, compiling

when I compile the document I have a problem. I need to have the same space between the lines. You can see that there are some lines that have different distances. I tried to change the code, but I didn't have success. This problem is occurring too with de figure list. I need to use 1.5 centimeters between the lines.

[image]

Partial Code:

```
% --- LISTA DE FIGURAS ---
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}


\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{FIGURA \ }
%\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{}
%\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{ \ -- \ }
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\dimexpr 7em}
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{\enspace--\enspace}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\newcommand{\listafiguras}
{
\begin{newpage}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{1.5\baselineskip} % Espacamento: 1.5

    \begin{center}
        \textbf{LISTA DE FIGURAS} \\ [1.5\baselineskip]
    \end{center}
    \@starttoc{lof}
\end{newpage}
}


% --- LISTA DE TABELAS ---

\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{TABELA \ }
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{7.2em}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{ \ -- \ }
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}

\newcommand{\listatabelas}
{
\begin{newpage}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{1.5\baselineskip} % Espacamento: 1.5

    \begin{center}
        \textbf{LISTA DE TABELAS} \\ [1.5\baselineskip]
    \end{center}
    \@starttoc{lot}
\end{newpage}
}
```

Comment: You are much much more likely to get help if you provide a small but full self contained example that others can copy and test as is. Here everything is going to be guess work since you do not provide any information about whst you are working with. Though I have a few guesses.

Comment: You also need to tell us (a) which document class you employ and whether or not you employ the `babel` package (and, if so, with which language(s) settings), Please also give us a sense of *why* the gaps in the LIst of Figures and, presumably, the List of Tables as well, are occurring. E.g, do the gaps occur whenever there's a new chapter?

Comment: Mico, the gaps occur whenever has a new chapter. I didn't see it.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}  %twoside, 
\usepackage{abakos}  %pacote com padrão da Abakos baseado no padrão da PUC
\usepackage{esint}   %melhora a escrita de integrais nas fórmulas
\usepackage{float}   %ajuda no posicionamento de figuras
\usepackage{pdfpages} %inserindo arquivos em pdf
\usepackage{verbatim} %comment
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} %borda texto
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} %borda texto
\usepackage{graphicx} %borda figura
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %borda figura

Answer (score 1):

The `\chapter` command inserts space into the List of Figures (LOF) and the List of Tables (LOT). The space, default 10pt, is specified via the `\addvspace` macro.

Before calling for the LOF (and LOT?) just insert:

```
\renewcommand{\addvspace}[1]{}
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy your code and add packages I think was needed. Into your `\listafiguras` and `\listatabelas`, you call the commands `\@starttoc{lot}` and `\@starttoc{lof}`.

This command contains the special character `@`; to be able to manipulate commands containing this character in the preamble of your document, you need to enclose the relevant part using `\makeatletter...\makeatother`.

And I think it's better use `\def` instead of `\newcommand`, since you're not put argument's on it. But with `\newcommand` works too. I run this 'MWE' and get this results:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% --- LISTA DE FIGURAS ---
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}


\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{FIGURA \ }
%\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{}
%\renewcommand{\cftfigaftersnum}{ \ -- \ }
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{\dimexpr 7em}
\renewcommand\cftfigaftersnum{\enspace--\enspace}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\makeatletter
\def\listafiguras{%
\begin{newpage}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{1.5\baselineskip} % Espacamento: 1.5
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{LISTA DE FIGURAS} \\[1.5\baselineskip]
    \end{center}
    \@starttoc{lof}
\end{newpage}
}
\makeatother


% --- LISTA DE TABELAS ---

\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{TABELA \ }
\setlength{\cfttabnumwidth}{7.2em}
\renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{ \ -- \ }
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}}

\makeatletter
\def\listatabelas{%
\begin{newpage}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \setlength{\baselineskip}{1.5\baselineskip} % Espacamento: 1.5
    \begin{center}
        \textbf{LISTA DE TABELAS} \\[1.5\baselineskip]
    \end{center}
    \@starttoc{lot}
\end{newpage}
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listafiguras
\listatabelas

\newpage

\blindtext[5]

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\captionof{table}{Tabela}
\end{minipage}

\blindtext[5]
\blindtext[5]
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\captionof{table}{Tabela}
\captionof{figure}{Figura}
\end{minipage}
\blindtext[5]

***Repeat this commmands***

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\captionof{table}{Tabela}
\end{minipage}

\blindtext[5]
\blindtext[5]
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\captionof{table}{Tabela}
\captionof{figure}{Figura}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Technically, `\def` is not supported LaTeX syntax (it's not described in the LaTeX manual) and should not be used unless you really know what you're doing. I'd go with `\newcommand` here...

Comment: I use a lot \def's. But with newcommand works fine too. I will learn more about when use \def or not.

Comment: I use mostly `\def` too ;-) The outstanding difference is that `\newcommand` checks whether the command already exists, so that you don't do `\newcommand\begin{BOOM}` by accident (for example). With `\newcommand` is also easier to define a command with an optional argument, like `\newcommand\mycmd[2][default]{Optional:(#1); Mandatory:(#2)}`. You can do that with `\def` too, but it's a lot more work. There's also `\NewDocumentCommand`, from the `xparse` package, which is much more flexible than `\newcommand`.